# Finding the reason for my app crashing

Tags: java, android, widget

I started playing around with Android a week ago. That's also the time i started learning Java. After about 100 tutorials and endless nights of trial and error, i tried to build my first app:

I'm trying to build an app that calls a REST-Service, gets back a JSON answer, parses this answer and displays it in the regular app. So long, so good - the app works and displays the time the next bus leaves in front of my apartment.
Then I got overwhelmed with the possibilities... I built my first appwidget, set up a service that fires every minute to update that widget. (i know - way too often. But for the sake of trying i left it with 60 seconds update interval).

## PROBLEMS

1) The app crashes unexpectedly about every 4th to 5th time i start it. I use my phone (HTC One) for debugging via ADB. The debugger works fine for all the files I created on my own, but shows me the "error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)"-Error. Which means I can't get any more information about the problem.
2) The widget won't update the textfield. I put a "tba" placeholder in there.

## WHAT I DID SO FAR

1) Tried to get the debugger to work by searching a solution here and on several other forums. The described error seems to be a common problem, but the solutions (reinstall Eclipse, the ADT, re-download all the android-ressources) didn't work for me. 
I searched for reasons in the different files (Layout, Java-Code, Manifest, etc.) that could cause these crashes. On my system, there are no compiling errors or warnings anymore.
2) Tried different approaches, but always end up with the RemoteView solution to update the textfield. Used several example projects with similar widgets, adjusted these and tried to apply the ideas to my project.

## WHERE I NEED YOUR HELP

1) Hints how to get rid of the debugging problem, help my find any newbie/beginner errors that could cause those crashes, hints on areas where i might have followed the wrong tutorials and got anything completely wrong
2) Any idea why i can't get the widget to update

## RESOURCES

I exported the complete Project into a ZIP-File: http://www.mikezweifel.ch/ZVV.zip

LogCat (errors portion):

```
07-20 10:07:26.642: E/Trace(11586): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
07-20 10:07:26.682: E/AndroidRuntime(11586): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-20 10:07:26.682: E/AndroidRuntime(11586): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver ch.mikezweifel.android.zvvstationsabfrage.WidgetProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.mikezweifel.android.zvvstationsabfrage.WidgetProvider
07-20 10:07:26.682: E/AndroidRuntime(11586):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2518)
07-20 10:07:26.682: E/AndroidRuntime(11586):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
07-20 10:07:26.682: E/AndroidRuntime(11586):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1417)
07-20 10:07:26.682: E/AndroidRuntime(11586):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-20 10:07:26.682: E/AndroidRuntime(11586):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
07-20 10:07:26.682: E/AndroidRuntime(11586):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5536)
07-20 10:07:26.682: E/AndroidRuntime(11586):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-20 10:07:26.682: E/AndroidRuntime(11586):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-20 10:07:26.682: E/AndroidRuntime(11586):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1074)
07-20 10:07:26.682: E/AndroidRuntime(11586):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:841)
07-20 10:07:26.682: E/AndroidRuntime(11586):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-20 10:07:26.682: E/AndroidRuntime(11586): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.mikezweifel.android.zvvstationsabfrage.WidgetProvider
07-20 10:07:26.682: E/AndroidRuntime(11586):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
07-20 10:07:26.682: E/AndroidRuntime(11586):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
07-20 10:07:26.682: E/AndroidRuntime(11586):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
07-20 10:07:26.682: E/AndroidRuntime(11586):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2513)
07-20 10:07:26.682: E/AndroidRuntime(11586):    ... 10 more
```

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

royassas

Comment: it would be helpful if you could post Logcat

Comment: and code of the activity where the crash occurs

Comment: You know that dialog message that says your app has stopped? It actually says "Read the Logcat" ;)

Comment: Since you are so new to android, if you don't know what logcat is: "adb logcat"...You will find it an absolute necessity to do anything in android.

Comment: The Logcat! Thanks for the tip spartygw. I added the error portion of it to my question. Couldn't find the problem with the receiver, yet.

Comment: Ahhhh! I had the Widget Broadcast receiver within my main activity instead of in a new class... my Widget finally updates! yes!

Comment: It all works now. Thanks alot Alamri, vikram, Karakuri and especially @sportygw for your help. The newbie is satisfied for now :-) How can i flag the question as answered?

Comment: @royassas You can post your problem description, research findings, and finally the solution as an answer below. You can then accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the continuous force-quits was that my Widget Provider class (WidgetProvider.java) was nested inside the main 'Startseite' activity. After placing the class in its separate file (but still in the same package) everything worked out quite well.

As for the "couldn't find source" problem: Google has the solution to this here (http://source.android.com/source/building.html) - a bit too much work for me right now to build the sourcecode.But after getting the source, one can reference it in Eclipse.

Comment: if someone wants the new source-ZIP, post me